# How can set Font and Background color at child node of JXTreeTable

Tags: java, swing, tablecellrenderer, jxtreetable, treecellrenderer

I have a simple Java swing application. So I have a JPanel with a JXTreeTable. I can insert into this TreeTable, soma row with child node, this is ok.

Now if I try to run my application, I can see this:

[image]

Also this is ok. So, now if I try to exapand one or more NODE I can see this:

[image]

I want know if is possible to change the rendere (set anothe background or another font color for the NODE child.

This is the code that I use to create JXTreeTable.

```
private void createTable(List<Entrate> v,String tipoConto){
    tableCatEntrate = new CustomTreeTableEntrate(v,tipoConto);
    daiProprietaJTableCatEntrate();
    jscrollPaneCatEntrate.setViewportView(tableCatEntrate);
}
```

This is the CustomTreeTableEntralte class:

```
public class CustomTreeTableEntrate extends JXTreeTable{

    public CustomTreeTableEntrate(List<Entrate> listaConti,String tipoConto){
        setTreeTableModel(new RandomTextTreeTableModel(listaConti,tipoConto));
        setRowSelectionAllowed(false);
        this.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new CustomTreeTableSpeseXCategoriaSpese());
    }
    class RandomTextTreeTableModel extends DefaultTreeTableModel {
        public final NumberFormat decimalFormatter2 = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");
        DefaultMutableTreeTableNode Root = null;
        final String[] ColName = {"","Acquisti/Vendite","Uscite","Entrate","Saldo"};
        //public LinkedHashMap<String, Entrate> mappaConti = new LinkedHashMap<String, Entrate>();
        String tipoConto;

        RandomTextTreeTableModel(List<Entrate>listaConti,String tipoConto) {
            Root = new DefaultMutableTreeTableNode();
            this.setRoot(Root);
            for (Entrate conti : listaConti) {
                DefaultMutableTreeTableNode node = new DefaultMutableTreeTableNode(conti);
                Root.add(node);
                if(conti.getListaContiFigli()!=null){
                    for (Entrate contoFiglio : conti.getListaContiFigli()) {
                        node.add(new DefaultMutableTreeTableNode(contoFiglio));
                        mappaConti.put(contoFiglio.getDescrizione(), contoFiglio);
                    }
                }
                contoTotale.setTotale(conti.getTotale()+contoTotale.getTotale());
                contoTotale.setTotalePubblico(conti.getTotalePubblico()+contoTotale.getTotalePubblico());
                contoTotale.setEntrate(conti.getEntrate()+contoTotale.getEntrate());
                contoTotale.setUscite(conti.getUscite()+contoTotale.getUscite());
            }

            DefaultMutableTreeTableNode node = new DefaultMutableTreeTableNode(contoTotale);
            Root.add(node);
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(Object arg0, int arg1) {
            try{
                if(arg1==0){
                    int numberElement = ((DefaultMutableTreeTableNode)arg0).getChildCount();
                    if(numberElement<=0)
                        return null;
                    //Conti c = (Conti)((DefaultMutableTreeTableNode)arg0).getChildAt(0).getUserObject();
                    return "";
                }
                Entrate c = (Entrate)((DefaultMutableTreeTableNode)arg0).getUserObject();
                if(c==null)
                    return null;
                if (arg1 == 0) {
                    return "";
                }else if (arg1 == 1) {
                    return c.getDescrizione();
                }else if (arg1 == 2) {
                    return decimalFormatter2.format(c.getUscite());
                }else if (arg1 == 3) {
                    return decimalFormatter2.format(c.getEntrate());
                }else if (arg1 == 4 && tipoConto!=null && tipoConto.equalsIgnoreCase(WFConst.TIPO_CONTO_DEFAULT_AMMINISTRAZIONE_PRIVATO)) {
                    return decimalFormatter2.format(c.getTotale());
                }else if (arg1 == 4 && tipoConto!=null && tipoConto.equalsIgnoreCase(WFConst.TIPO_CONTO_DEFAULT_AMMINISTRAZIONE_PUBBLICO)) {
                    return decimalFormatter2.format(c.getTotalePubblico());
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return arg0;
        }



    }

}
```

This is the TreeTableRenderer, I think that the problem, is in thi class because if I try to execute a Debug, I can't go into getTreeCellRendererComponent.

```
public class CustomTreeTableSpeseXCategoriaSpese extends JLabel implements TreeCellRenderer, TableCellRenderer {
    /**
     * 
     */
    DefaultTreeCellRenderer defaultRenderer = new DefaultTreeCellRenderer();
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4842418316518803090L;
    private Font fontTotale = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 12);
    private Font fontNegativo = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 12);




    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, 
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        setOpaque(true);



        if(column ==1){
            setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        }else{
            setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        }

        if (row== table.getRowCount()-1) {
            setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            setBackground( Color.RED );
            setFont(fontTotale);
        }else if(row != table.getRowCount() && column !=4){
            setForeground( Color.BLACK );
            setBackground(new Color(200, 200, 200));
            setFont(UtilitySwing.getTableFont());
        }else if(row != table.getRowCount()-1 && column ==4){
            String valore = value.toString();
            if(valore.startsWith("-")){
                setForeground(Color.red);
                setFont(fontNegativo);
            }else{
                setForeground(Color.blue);
                setFont(fontNegativo);
            }
        }
        setText(value != null ? value.toString() : "<null>");
        return this;
    }



    @Override
    public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value,
            boolean selected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row,
            boolean hasFocus) {
        setOpaque(true);

        if(expanded){
            setForeground(Color.PINK);
            setBackground( Color.PINK );
            setFont(fontTotale);
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are already using the `TreeCellRenderer`, so you're close.
All you need to do is access the model (something like `DefaultTreeModel`) and use `getPathToRoot()` to see how deep in the tree you are and change the renderer accordingly.

An example:

```
DefaultTreeCellRenderer defaultTreeCellRenderer = new DefaultTreeCellRenderer() {
    @Override
    public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value,
                                                  boolean selected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row,
                                                  boolean hasFocus) {
        setOpaque(true);

        DefaultTreeModel model = (DefaultTreeModel) tree.getModel();
        if (model.getPathToRoot((TreeNode) value).length > 2) {
            //Do your rendering goodness here
        } else if (expanded) {
            setForeground(Color.PINK);
            setBackground(Color.PINK);
            setFont(fontTotale);
        }
        return this;
    }
};
```

**Note** I made some assumptions, so please correct to your need accordingly.

1. The model is a `DefaultTreeModel`
2. The node is a `TreeNode`
3. You only care if the node is at least 3 levels deep

Also, check out the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeModel.html#getPathToRoot(javax.swing.tree.TreeNode)) for this function to make sure it is what you need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If i try to execute your code, I can set background color only for the first column and not the child node but the root node. Can you help me?

Comment: @bircastri Have you tried adapting your `getTableCellRendererComponent()` from `TableCellRenderer` with a similar logic? The example that I gave only implemented the `TreeCellRenderer` part of your custom renderer.

Comment: Ok, only one question, how can retrieve what is the column to renderer? because in the gettableCellrendererComponent() I have the column value in TreeCellRendere I don't have this information

Comment: I don't think you need to worry about the column inside the `TreeCellRenderer`. But the `TableCellRenderer` does give you the row and column info. Let me know if this is working out for you.

Comment: mmm, I don't know because if I use only TableCellRenderer I have a correct layout but I want also change the layout of child node